# How to find your app on google store?

Tags: android, search, google-play

My app on Android Market (Google Play) has a name, Truck Route Uk, but when I search for it with that name it does not show up. But when I search without a space (like Truckrouteuk) it shows up. How can I solve this? Because of this I will be losing many users.

Comment: Have you tried including "Truck Route Uk" in the description?

Comment: Yes,and i did it few times. And Title name also is Truck Route UK. I don't understand whats wrong with it. I understand that is SEO but how people start to find it,if its not show up even when u entering right title. Its like paradox.

Answer (score 1):

It had been loaded to the store but you can't search for it for some hours after load. Just wait. To look at your app now you can only use a special link that you got in console